# Laravel 5.6 validate required_without multiple

Tags: laravel

I use laravel 5.6 and I try to use validate to check my input.

But I have an issue with required_without.

I have 4 input : heure_bureau / heure_supp_bureau / heure_terrain / heure_supp_terrain

I must fill one input at least. So if I fill heure_bureau, the others aren't necessary.

So I use this code :

```
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'heures_bureau'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without:heures_supp_bureau,heures_terrain,heures_supp_terrain|before:07h45',
        'heures_supp_bureau'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without:heures_bureau,heures_terrain,heures_supp_terrain|before:13h15',
        'heures_terrain'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without:heures_bureau,heures_supp_bureau,heures_supp_terrain|before:07h45',
        'heures_supp_terrain'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without:heures_bureau,heures_supp_bureau,heures_terrain|before:13h15'
    ], $messages);
```

But it doesn't work. I have an error for each other input when I fill one.
If I use requried_without with only one input, it work well but not when I use it with multiple inputs.

Where am I wrong ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
 $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'heures_bureau'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without_all:heures_supp_bureau,heures_terrain,heures_supp_terrain|before:07h45',
    'heures_supp_bureau'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without_all:heures_bureau,heures_terrain,heures_supp_terrain|before:13h15',
    'heures_terrain'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without_all:heures_bureau,heures_supp_bureau,heures_supp_terrain|before:07h45',
    'heures_supp_terrain'    => 'nullable|date_format:"H\hi"|required_without_all:heures_bureau,heures_supp_bureau,heures_terrain|before:13h15'
], $messages);
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine required_if and required_without ?